# How can i view rar or zip file content before downloading it?

Tags: zip, rar

How can i view rar or zip file content before downloading it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** per comment, adding the suggestions from the linked summary page. One may be outdated as of 2018-06.

---

Would [THESE](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/2-ways-to-extractview-any-archive-file-before-downloading/) help? They offer two solutions:

- [ArchView (Firefox plugin)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/archview/) (appears to be old now...)
- [WobZIP (Online Service)](http://wobzip.org/)

Comment: Link-only answers generally aren't good as the link can break in the future...

Answer (score 0):

In general principle, this isn't possible. To view something, you have to download at least part of it.

However, you may be able to download the header of the archive (for particular formats) and read that. If it contains a list of filenames and sizes, that should give you enough information to "view the content" before downloading the entire file.

Most formats have a header segment with a known length (or recorded in the first few bytes of the file), so grabbing the first 8 bytes (4 for the type and 4 for the header length, let's say), then the rest of the header (based on the length) may be viable. It seems a bit awkward though.

In the case of a non-solid archive, you could also request a particular chunk corresponding to a file from the server, but I'm not sure how you'd go about decompressing it.

Answer (score 0):

For ZIP archive this is not possible, since information about files, stored in archive is located at the end of archive (central directory) and before each compressed file, i.e.  compressed file data  second file and so on.
So, you can only see information about first file in archive, and to see all further info you need to download data.